# Compare 2 variables at different stages of the test

Tags: web-services, jmeter, automated-tests, assertions, beanshell

i have this scheme in JMeter:

*Get the balance value* (GET) put in var **mainBalance**
*Place a recharge* (POST)
*Verify resulted balance* (GET) - put in var **updatedBalance** such as **updatedBalance** is **mainBalance** + **10$**
All values must be type float.

I`m stuck at the last step: I've put a BeanShell assertion but doesn't work. It think that i get the values in the wrong way and also i don`t do the calculation as JMeter wants. I also tried with *vars.get(String.valueOf("mainBalance"))*

```
float a = new float(vars.get("mainBalance"));
float b = new float(vars.get("updatedBalance"));
if(b != (a + 10)) {
    Failure = true;
}
```

This is the log error:

Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``float a = new float("mainBalance"); float b = new float("updatedBalance");  if(b . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 1, column 20.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Float data type to represent money operations, go for at least [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead
2. Don't use Beanshell as it might become a performance bottleneck, go for [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead.

The relevant code would be something like:

```
def a = new BigDecimal(vars.get('mainBalance'))
def b = new BigDecimal(vars.get('updatedBalance'))
if (b.compareTo(a.add(new BigDecimal('10'))) != 0) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
}
```

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: I don`t understand groovy code very well, seems to me that there should be 

**if (b.compareTo(a.add(new BigDecimal('10'))) = 0) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
}**

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo